# Python BFS not giving the shortest path

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, breadth-first-search

I have implemented breadth-first search according to the pseudo-code in CLRS.

However, it's not always giving me the shortest path between two nodes, as you can clearly see on the image below.

[image]

Here it went 10 -> 5 -> 1 -> 6 -> 0 but it should clearly have gone through 10 -> 1 -> 0.

Nodes and edges:

```
[[6, 7], [5, 0, 4], [6, 0, 4], [9, 4], [8, 2], [4, 9, 10], [1], [0], [9, 0], [7, 7], [8, 3, 1]]
```

Distances:

```
[0, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4]
```

Colors ( 2 stands for black ):

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Predecessors:

```
[None, 6, 4, 10, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 5, 5]
```

I can't figure out what's happening here as it seems that I'm doing exactly what's described in CLRS. Most of the times it gets the right path but sometimes it goes wrong for unknown reasons. There's also a possibility that I'm just drawing the graph wrong with networkx, I don't know.

The overall idea is that the code below generates random graphs until it finds one where it's possible to draw the shortest path between nodes a and b (i.e. a and b are not disjoint ).

Graph() is my own class and nx.Graph() is a different function from the networkx library.

```
from collections import deque
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self,graph):
        self.nodes = graph
        self.colors = [0] * len(graph)
        self.distances = [len(graph) + 1000] * len(graph)
        self.predecessor = [None] * len(graph)
        self.queue = deque()
        self.nodelist = ['red'] * len(graph)

    def BFS(self,start):
        self.__init__(self.nodes)
        self.colors[start] = 1 #GRAY
        self.distances[start] = 0
        self.queue.append(start)
        while self.queue:
            current = self.queue.popleft()
            for node in self.nodes[current]:
                if self.colors[node] == 0: #WHITE
                    self.colors[node] = 1 #GRAY
                    self.distances[node] = self.distances[current] + 1
                    self.predecessor[node] = current
                    self.queue.append(node)
            self.colors[current] = 2 #BLACK

    def draw_path(self,start,end):
        self.nodelist[start] = 'green'
        previous = end
        while previous != start:
            self.nodelist[previous] = 'green'
            previous = self.predecessor[previous]
            print(previous,self.distances[previous])
        return


while 1:
    try:
        graph = []

        for i in range(0,15):
            t = random.randint(0,3)
            if t == 0:
                graph.append([random.randint(0,10)])
            if t == 1:
                graph.append([random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10)])
            if t == 2:
                graph.append([random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10)])
        x = Graph(graph)
        a = 0
        b = 10

        x.BFS(0)
        x.draw_path(a,b)
        print(x.nodes)
        print(x.distances)
        print(x.colors)
        print(x.predecessor)

        y = nx.Graph()
        for i in range(len(graph)):
            y.add_node(i)

        for i in range(len(graph)):
            for j in graph[i]:
                y.add_edge(i,j)

        graph_label = 'Shortest path from {0} to {1}'.format(a,b)
        nx.draw_networkx(y,with_labels=True,node_color=x.nodelist)
        plt.title(graph_label)
        plt.show()
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Quick check, is the distance correct?

Comment: Yes, they are. If you run the code, it will print the distances side by side with the nodes.

Comment: So the distance from 10-> 0 is 2 as expected?

Comment: Actually I get the distance array [0, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4] so 10 -> 0 is not 2 but 4.

Comment: what is the `[[6, 7], [5, 0, 4], [6, 0, 4], [9, 4], [8, 2], [4, 9, 10], [1], [0], [9, 0], [7, 7], [8, 3, 1]]` ? does that mean node 0 connecting with  node 6 and 7 etc? this is not the graph you draw right?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. And it's supposed to be the graph that you're seeing in the picture.

Comment: If the edges are based from the graph above, your algo actually is correct.

Comment: If the algo is correct then why it's not going through the shortest path? It should have gone through 10 -> 1 -> 0.

Comment: Because the graph you provided to the algo is not what do you think it is, there is nothing wrong with your BFS, the error may be in other parts.

Comment: Node 10 is connected to 1, [8, 3, 1]. Node 1 is connected to 0, [5, 0, 4]. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In your question, you provide `[[6, 7], [5, 0, 4], [6, 0, 4], [9, 4], [8, 2], [4, 9, 10], [1], [0], [9, 0], [7, 7], [8, 3, 1]]` -> node 0 connect to `[6, 7]`. This is **directed** graph, and the **start node** is 0, not 10, you just reverse the path from the end node.

Comment: So you're telling me this is a directed graph and I missed the arrows in my drawing. Now I get your point.

Comment: Cool, I think problem solved

Comment: You can copy and paste that as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question, the provided graph is

```
[[6, 7], [5, 0, 4], [6, 0, 4], [9, 4], [8, 2], [4, 9, 10], [1], [0], [9, 0], [7, 7], [8, 3, 1]]
```

Which suggest that this is a **directed** graph, and as the start node is 0 not 10, the path is correct, as it travels backward from **end** to **start**:

```
10 <- 5 <- 1 <- 6 <- 0
```